# How to link objects using objectIds in parse

Tags: parse-platform, foreign-keys

parse gives this example...

> Internally, the Parse framework will store the referred-to object in
>   just one place, to maintain consistency. You can also link objects
>   using just their objectIds like so:

```
var post = new Post();
post.id = "1zEcyElZ80";

myComment.set("parent", post);
```

say i want to link a new comment to an existing post, how would i go about this? given i have the post objectId.

Comment: Exactly like it says, I always design the tables first using the databrowser and set up the foreign key relationship through the data browser by making the column a pointer to another table although I believe that Parse will automatically detect what type of object it is and set up the foreign key for you. You would go about that by making your comment table with a postid column or in this case a "parent" column which would be the pointer I described above.

Comment: Thanks Ian, hmmm... i did exactly that. any idea why i get this "Failed to create new object, with error code: invalid type for key parent, expected relation<Post>, but got *Post"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I said in my comment, I prefer to set it up before hand in the parse data browser, but you would want to use a **relation** between the post and the comment not a pointer as I previously stated.

This is because a pointer should be used for a one-to-one relationship and a relation for a one-to-many relationship as a comment would be to a post.

https://parse.com/questions/pointer-vs-relation

Answer (score 3):

Ian, unless that target page was edited, your answer is incorrect. As per that page:

> A good rule of thumb is, use a pointer for a one-to-one or one-to-many
>   relationship. Use a relation when you have a many-to-many
>   relationship.

It would seem there is some fuzziness in this area that many are not happy about.

Comment: I think you're right. The Comment would be its own Parse object with a column(property) that is a pointer to its parent Post object. Relations are for many-to-many. See [Parse Docs](https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#objects-pointers/iOS)

Answer (score 0):

This is in Java using Pointers to build relationship.

```
ParseObject favorite = new ParseObject("favorite");
myComment.put("parent", ParseObject.createWithoutData("post_id", "1zEcyElZ80"));
myComment.saveInBackground();
```